# Table-cell property ignores width

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have set a CSS property table-cell for a div. I have also specified the width for the div and set overflow hidden, but because of the table-cell property the div does not care about the width. If I place any large image, it goes out of the width.
How can I use the table-cell and use the fixed width for the div?

```
.right{
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the full CSS and HTML of the page having the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strange, [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfnKg/3/) seems to work for me.

What browser are you having problems in?

Also, to force a maximum width for your table cells, use the `max-width` property. You can [see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/83K7X/), and the code is below.

HTML:

```
<div class='table'>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='right'>hey</div>
  </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table;
}
.tr {
    display: table-row;
}
.right{
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 400px;
    outline: 1px solid #888;
}​
```

Comment: That's the same link in my answer!

Comment: I still can't replicate this problem: "If I place any large image, it goes out of the width." Again, what browser and version are you testing in?

Comment: can you see that I changed the width of right in your example to 100px, and the image size is over 100px, so it should hide it but it is just expanding whole div. I'm using FF latest.

Answer (score 5):

`display: table-cell` will follow the table sizing rules - if the content is too big, it will expand to make it fit.

Do you really need to use `display: table-cell`? To make it work, you'd have to wrap it in another div, give it a width of 400 and set it to `overflow: hidden` but that seems counter-productive.